msal4j.JsonHelper cannot be initialized at version 1.11.2
I am using kusto.Ingest version 2.5.1 and got this error:
*ERROR*| [Timer-985]| com.microsoft.azure.kusto.ingest.ResourceManager| Error in refreshIngestionAuthToken.| com.microsoft.azure.kusto.ingest.exceptions.IngestionServiceException: Error refreshing IngestionAuthToken
    at com.microsoft.azure.kusto.ingest.ResourceManager.refreshIngestionAuthToken(ResourceManager.java:199)
    at com.microsoft.azure.kusto.ingest.ResourceManager.access$500(ResourceManager.java:22)
    at com.microsoft.azure.kusto.ingest.ResourceManager$1RefreshIngestionAuthTokenTask.run(ResourceManager.java:102)
    at java.util.TimerThread.mainLoop(Timer.java:555)
    at java.util.TimerThread.run(Timer.java:505)
Caused by: com.microsoft.azure.kusto.data.exceptions.DataServiceException: Error acquiring ApplicationAccessToken
    at com.microsoft.azure.kusto.data.auth.ConfidentialAppTokenProviderBase.acquireNewAccessToken(ConfidentialAppTokenProviderBase.java:32)
    at com.microsoft.azure.kusto.data.auth.MsalTokenProviderBase.acquireAccessToken(MsalTokenProviderBase.java:46)
    at com.microsoft.azure.kusto.data.ClientImpl.initHeaders(ClientImpl.java:196)
    at com.microsoft.azure.kusto.data.ClientImpl.executeToJsonResult(ClientImpl.java:135)
    at com.microsoft.azure.kusto.data.ClientImpl.execute(ClientImpl.java:76)
    at com.microsoft.azure.kusto.data.ClientImpl.execute(ClientImpl.java:71)
    at com.microsoft.azure.kusto.data.ClientImpl.execute(ClientImpl.java:66)
    at com.microsoft.azure.kusto.ingest.ResourceManager.refreshIngestionAuthToken(ResourceManager.java:190)
    ... 4 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class com.microsoft.aad.msal4j.JsonHelper
    at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.reportGet(CompletableFuture.java:357)
    at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.get(CompletableFuture.java:1928)
    at com.microsoft.azure.kusto.data.auth.ConfidentialAppTokenProviderBase.acquireNewAccessToken(ConfidentialAppTokenProviderBase.java:30)

The error is saying the class JsonHelper from msal4j cannot be initialized. According to its documentation, Kusto.Ingest 2.5.1 is using Kusto.Data 2.5.1, and Kusto.Data 2.5.1 is using msal4j 1.9.1 by default. However, in JsonHelper from msal4j 1.9.1, JsonHelper class does not have an initializer method. So I upgraded it to version 1.11.1 so the initialize method exists:
private JsonHelper() {
}

However, I am still getting the same error from the above. Here are the steps I checked:

The manifest and the embeds dependency and export dependency shows the msal4j is at 1.11.2, kusto.data is at 2.5.1, kusto.ingest is at 2.5.1
I decompiled the JsonHelper.class file from the jar file and validated it does have initializer method.

Am I missing anything?
For reference,
masl4j 1.11.2 source code: https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-java/blob/v1.11.2/src/main/java/com/microsoft/aad/msal4j/JsonHelper.java
msal4j 1.9.1 source code: https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-java/blob/v1.9.1/src/main/java/com/microsoft/aad/msal4j/JsonHelper.java

Please check your dependencies in pom.xml (if you use maven of course which is not clear from your original question) and check this answer, it looks similar to your problem Could not initialize class com.microsoft.aad.msal4j.JsonHelper while connecting to SQL Server with AD password authentication
